# How to hide inputscope for textbox in windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I want to hide the inputscope of all my textboxes on the page when the click event of a button fires, how can I do this?

Comment: Any effort so far? This is not a good way to ask in my opinion. Show your effort first so people might show theirs.

Comment: An input scope is a constraint. What are you talking about? Are you trying to say you want to limit the input of the user?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind got the answer,

just needed to focus on something else, so used this.focus()